# delete a snapshot created before LVM extension

Tags: vmware-esxi, lvm, snapshot

I believe that snapshots and disk extensions are not friends, having said that...

Is it safe to delete a VMWare snapshot created before adding a new virtual hdd to my LVM partition?

What I mean is:

1. Create a VMWare snapshot
2. Add a new virtual hdd to my VM
3. extend server's LVM partition with the new virtual hdd
4. delete the VMWare snapshot

Is this going to break my server? can I safely reboot it after delete the snapshot?

NOTE: I am talking about Virtual machine snapshots and not LVM snapshots.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly safe.

If you created the snapshot while the VM was powered off even revertig to the snapshot should be no problem. I wouldn't want to try reverting to a snapshot that was created while the VM was powered off though, those are never really clean.

Operations like this are exactly what snapshots are for.